# Formatting date using datetimepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I am using the datetimepicker option (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#basic_examples).

```
$('#basic_example_3').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
});
```

If the user selects no hours or minutes (i.e. 12/11/2014 12:00 am), I would don't wish to display the time, but just display 12/11/2014.  I realize I could use the `onClose`, and use JavaScript to manually trim the time, but am asking whether there is a better way to do so using the plugin.

Also, I will be sending the datetime to the server, and would like it in DATETIME format (i.e. 2014-12-11 18:30:00).  I could parse it serverside, however, am asking whether there is a a better way to do so using the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution, but it works. Ideally, `moment()` wouldn't be used, but some embedded datetimepicker method.  I tried to do so, but couldn't seem to access hours and minutes.

```
$('#basic_example_3').datetimepicker({
    stepMinute: 5,
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
    onClose: function(dateText, inst){
        var datetime = moment(dateText, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); //  12/11/2014 12:00 am => 2014-12-11 18:30:00
        dateText = dateText.replace(/12:00 am$/, '');   //Get rid of minutes if midnight
        $(this).val(dateText);
        $.post('ajax.php',{datetime:datetime},function(json) {
            //display errors if necessary
            }
        );
}});
```